# How to have Allegro on CLion?

Tags: c++, c++11, clion, allegro, allegro5

I looked everywhere but I can't see to find the answer. Is there a way to put Allegro onto CLion? I have tried looking all over stackoverflow, google, and youtube. I just can't find it. If you guys can help me it will be appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: This question is independent from CLion. You need to learn CMake, which is the build configuration system used by CLion. See for example https://cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried: brew install allegro.
Look here for more information, https://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Installing_with_homebrew.

I think you can just compile using -lalleg in the terminal as well.

I misunderstood the question, nevermind.

Comment: If you think you misunderstood the question and thus your answer is not a good one, you should rather delete it than edit "I misunderstood the question"